# is it possible to use cdk virtual scroll in ngbaccordion

Tags: accordion, ng-bootstrap, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

Need to know is it possible to use this new feature @angular/cdk/scrolling in a specific accordion like ng-bootstrap's (in mat-accordion it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/virtual-scroll-expansion-panels?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahzm1v?file=app%2Faccordion-basic.ts

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible a component consisting of the virtual scroll will reside inside the accordion component.

check the [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mba48j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fscroll.component.ts)

**accordian.component.html**:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" >
    <ngb-panel [title]="num" *ngFor="let num of numbers">
        <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute,
            non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua
            put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore
            wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
            <cdk-virtual-scroll> Loading..... </cdk-virtual-scroll>
            occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore
            sustainable VHS.
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

**EDIT**: 
The [stackblitz code above](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mba48j?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordian.component.ts) is still relevant. The following CSS makes the accordian inside a virtual scroll.

```
  ngb-accordion {
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: i need panels are as virtual scrolling, not data in content (like in mat-acc)

Comment: So the virtual scroll is on the outside and each virtual scroll item is an expansive accordion panel, right?

Comment: ye, that's true